# What criteria should I pay attention to when choosing a place to perform an MRI?

Tags: mri

What criteria should I pay attention to when choosing a place to perform an MRI? The MRI is done to diagnose the source of pain in an articulation (e.g., elbow tendinopathy).

One criterion is the number of teslas the MRI scanner has, as [it might impact the quality of the diagnosis](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/5671/43). What else should I consider?

I am only interested in criteria that could affect the quality of medical care the patient receives (e.g., one can ignore health insurance considerations).

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for criteria of best quality IRM ? Or best medical care ?

Comment: @Blue_Elephant Any criterion that could help improve the medical care. (criteria of best quality IRM would be a subset)

Comment: What does "IRM" stands for?

Comment: @dev101 IRM = MRI in French (and probably a few other languages)

Comment: I thought it was a 'reverse' typo. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A higher Tesla magnet generally equates to a higher quality image. Closed (the traditional round-shaped magnet bore) or oval MRIs generally produce a higher quality image than open MRIs, so avoid an open MRI unless you're severely claustrophobic. A newer MRI machine would be preferable to one installed, say, 15 or 20 years ago, all other factors being equal. That's really about it. The skill of the radiologist who will be reading the MRI is certainly important, but that's not something you can easily compare or choose.